# What is the minimum size of the set and minimum power of a strict relation that can be used for a base case in an inductive proof?

Tags: proof-writing, relations

Consider the strict order binary relation $xRy$ over the set $A$ with the following properties:

**irreflexive** $\forall x  \in A \neg (xRx$)

**asymmetric**  $\forall xy  \in A (xRy \Rightarrow \neg yRx)$

**transitive**  $\forall xyz \in A (xRy \land yRz \Rightarrow xRz)$

**Non Empty Set** $A \neq \emptyset$

**Non Empty Relation** $R \neq \emptyset$

What is minimum size of the set $A$ over which the relation $R$ is defined?

I need to know the minimum size/power to use as a base case in an inductive proof of a strict order.

Here is my attempt to find the smallest set and relation with these properties. 
 Examining $\left\vert{A}\right\vert$ for values 1,2, and 3.

$\left\vert{A}\right\vert=1, A=\{a\}$ and there is only  possible relation is $R=\{(a,a)\}$ which is not irreflexive

$\left\vert{A}\right\vert=2, A=\{a,b\}$ and there are only two mutually exclusive possible relations  $R=\{(a,b)\}$ or $R=\{(b,a)\}$ each of which gives a relation that is asymmetric, vacuously irreflexive and vacuously transitivity. It has power $R^1$

$\left\vert{A}\right\vert=3, A=\{a,b,c\}$ then $R=\{(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)\}$ which is asymmetric, irreflexive and transitivity

It seems to me $\left\vert{A}\right\vert=3$ is the only case where true (as opposed vacuous) transitivity holds. It has power $R^2$ or ($R \circ R$). $xRy$ is intended to formally represent a relation **IsOnTopOf** where one object is physically placed on top of another. Which base case is best suited to this situation? I am not sure whether or not I can use the vacuously irreflexive and vacuously transitivity as a base case for an inductive proof

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.  You've shown that the minimum size is $2$, but for some reason you don't like that, so you give an answer of size $3$.  What is it that you want to know?

Comment: I was was not sure whether or not I could use the vacuously irreflexive and vacuously transitivity as a base case for an inductive proof. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Just let me reiterate.  People use a vacuous argument to establish the base for an induction all the time, and it's perfectly legitimate.  All that matters is that you prove the base is true.  How you prove it is up to you.

Comment: You have not assumed trichotomy so  if $A$ has at least $2$ members  $a,b$ you can let $R=\{(a,b)\},$ regardless of whether $A$ has any other members.

Comment: As @DanielWainfleet  points out I did not mention the trichotomy property. Is it implicit in the stated properties of $R$? (I do not know!) (@ saulspatz )

Comment: Trichotomy is not implied by the other properties. For a familiar example, let $A=\Bbb N$  and let $xRy$ iff $x$ is a proper divisor of $y$.